# Non latin text in SVG

Tags: svg, character-encoding

Take the following code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400"
    direction="rtl" xml:lang="fa">
    <title>...</title>
    <desc>...</desc>
    <text x="200" y="200"
        font-size="10">داستان SVG Tiny 1.2 طولا ني است.</text>
    </svg>
```

When I open this in my browser, I see:

```
Ø¯Ø§Ø³ØªØ§Ù† SVG Tiny 1.2 Ø·ÙˆÙ„Ø§ Ù†ÙŠ Ø§Ø³Øª.
```

This is the same for Russian, Hebrew, Greek, Chinese, Japanese etc.

In HTML this displays normally in my browser.

**How can I display non Latin characters in SVG?**

Comment: I've done so, but don't see anything I can use. Why would I look at UTF-16?

Comment: Just a long shot. I gor similar problems to print ãéîòüç for example and changing enconde to UTF-8 works for me

Comment: Make sure your SVG file is UTF-8 encoded.  Check your editor settings.